# OpenCV, Haar cascade classifier: scaling feature or computing image pyramid?

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

I read the paper of Viola and Jones. 
They stated clearly in the paper that their algorithm is faster than others because calculation of image pyramid is avoided by scaling feature rectangles.

But I googled around for a long time, only to find that OpenCV implements the image pyramid method instead of scaling the feature rectangles. And integral image is computed for all sub images in the pyramid. And this is done for every frame if this algorithm is used to process video in stead of picture.

What's the rationale of this choice? I don't quite get it.

All I can understand is completely the opposite: for video applications, scaling the features only needs to be done once, and the scaled features can be reused by all the frames. And only the integral image of the whole image needs to be computed .

Am I correct on this?

Viola and Jones also presented a 15fps frame rate on a Pentium 3 computer, but I hardly see anybody achieving that performance with the OpenCV implementation on modern computer. That's strange, isn't it?

Any input will be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to verify this by looking into their code. This is based on version 2.4.10. The short answer is: both. OpenCv scales the image according to the scale factor at which the detection is performed and it can also rescale the features at different window sizes according to the scale factor. Justification is bellow:
1. Looking at the older functions, cvHaarDetectObjectsForROC from objdetect module (haar.cpp). Notable arguments are the CvSize minSize, CvSize maxSize and const CvArr* _img, double scaleFactor, int minNeighbors.

```
CvSeq*
cvHaarDetectObjectsForROC( const CvArr* _img,
                     CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade, CvMemStorage* storage,
                     std::vector<int>& rejectLevels, std::vector<double>& levelWeights,
                     double scaleFactor, int minNeighbors, int flags,
                     CvSize minSize, CvSize maxSize, bool outputRejectLevels )
{
    CvMat stub, *img = (CvMat*)_img;
.... // skip a bit ahead to this part
    if( flags & CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE )
    {
        CvSize winSize0 = cascade->orig_window_size; // this would be the trained size of 24x24 pixels mentioned in the paper
        for( factor = 1; ; factor *= scaleFactor )
        {
           // detection window for current scale
           CvSize winSize = { cvRound(winSize0.width*factor), cvRound(winSize0.height*factor) };
           //resized image size
           CvSize sz = { cvRound( img->cols/factor ), cvRound( img->rows/factor ) };
           // take every possible scale factor as long as the resulting window doesn't exceed the maximum size given and is bigger than the minimum one
           if( winSize.width > maxSize.width || winSize.height > maxSize.height )
               break;
           if( winSize.width < minSize.width || winSize.height < minSize.height )
               continue;
           img1 = cvMat( sz.height, sz.width, CV_8UC1, imgSmall->data.ptr );
           ... // skip sum, square sum, tilted sums a.k.a interal image arrays initialization
           cvResize( img, &img1, CV_INTER_LINEAR ); // scaling down the image here
           cvIntegral( &img1, &sum1, &sqsum1, _tilted ); // compute integral representation for the scaled down version
           ...  //skip some lines
           cvSetImagesForHaarClassifierCascade( cascade, &sum1, &sqsum1, _tilted, 1. ) //-> set the structures and also rescales the feature according to the last parameter which is the scale factor.
          // Notice it is 1.0 because the image was scaled down this time.
          <call detection function with notable arguments: cascade,... factor, cv::Mat(&sum1), cv::Mat(&sqsum1) ...>
          // the above call is a parallel for that evaluates a window at a certain position in the image with the cascade classifier
          // note the class naming HaarDetectObjects_ScaleImage_Invoker in the actual code and skipped here.

        } // end for
    } // if
    else
    {
        int n_factors = 0; // total number of factors
        cvIntegral( img, sum, sqsum, tilted ); // -> makes a single integral image for the given image (the original one passed in the cvHaarDetectObjects)
        // below aims to see the total number of scale factors at which detection is performed.
         for( n_factors = 0, factor = 1;
             factor*cascade->orig_window_size.width < img->cols - 10 &&
             factor*cascade->orig_window_size.height < img->rows - 10;
             n_factors++, factor *= scaleFactor );
        ... // skip some lines
        for( ; n_factors-- > 0; factor *= scaleFactor )
        {
            CvSize winSize = { cvRound( cascade->orig_window_size.width * factor ), cvRound( cascade->orig_window_size.height * factor )};
            ... // skip check for minSize and maxSize here
            cvSetImagesForHaarClassifierCascade( cascade, sum, sqsum, tilted, factor ); // -> notice here the scale factor is given so that the trained Haar features can be rescaled.
            <parallel for detect call given a startX, endX and startY endY, window size and cascade> // Note the name here HaarDetectObjects_ScaleCascade_Invoker used in actual code and skipped here
        }
    } // end of if
... // skip rest
} // end of cvHaarDetectObjectsForROC function
```

2. If you take the new API (C++) the class CascadeClassifier if it loads the new .xml format of the cascade outputted by the traincascade.exe application will scale the image according to the scale factor (for Haars it should be up from what I know of). The detectMultiScale method of the class will default to the detectSingleScale method at some point in the code:

   ```
    if( !detectSingleScale( scaledImage, stripCount, processingRectSize, stripSize, yStep, factor, candidates, rejectLevels, levelWeights, outputRejectLevels ) )
        break; // from cascadedetect.cpp in the detectMultiScale method.
   ```

Possible reason I can think of: In order to have a unified design in C++ this is the only method that can achieve transparency with a single interface for different types of features.

I left the trail of thought in case I have understood something wrong or have omitted something another user can correct me by verifying this trail.